# Use checkbox to select item Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to be able to have a list of items and to select one using a checkbox:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="device in devices">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox"> {{ device.name }}
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If this can be done using a custom directive that would also be cool!

So the idea, that when a `checkbox` is checked the device would go into an `ng-model` and all the other checkboxes would be disabled.

I have a feeling there needs to be a custom model created, something like:

```
devices = [{
     name: "LED",
     checked: false,
     id: "98"
  },{
     name: "LED 2",
     checked: false,
     id: "8"
  },{
     name: "LED 3",
     checked: false,
     id: "78"
  }]
```

Just need some function to fire each time one checkbox is checked.

I expect that it can be done with a `ng-click` on the checkbox? And a two way data binding on the model for `canBeChecked`

```
devices = [{
         name: "LED",
         checked: false,
         id: "98",
         canBeChecked: true
      },{
         name: "LED 2",
         checked: false,
         id: "8",
         canBeChecked: true
      },{
         name: "LED 3",
         checked: false,
         id: "78",
         canBeChecked: true
      }]
```

Comment: Why a checkbox and not a radio button? Radio buttons are better for mutually exclusive options.

Comment: I know, but they don't have the same look and feel as checkboxes, they would be the better option, I just don't want to use them :)

Comment: That goes against [best practices](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/checkboxes-vs-radio-buttons/). What do you mean by "they don't have the same look and feel"?

Comment: @GregL: "best practices" are often ignored by the people in charge. As an engineer, you are told to build a feature and that's the end of story. I was charged with doing the very same thing not long ago, and it made no sense to quarrel with the boss :).

Comment: @GregL it does, but when you fill out a form, you tick one box don't you? (more often then not). And unfortunately my app is meant for the most basic of computer users (95% of the country :P)

Comment: @mingos do you mind upvoting the question just so i get 0 instead of -1

Comment: This looks like a very reasonable question. Sometimes you need to allow the user to choose "at most one" item, but radio buttons are designed to allow the user to choose "exactly one" item, and they don't easily allow you to uncheck them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over your collection and display a checkbox for each:

```
<div ng-repeat="device in devices">
    <label>
        {{ device.name }}
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="device.checked" ng-click="change(device)">
    </label>
</div>
```

Note that the checkbox also has the `ng-click` directive. This is what you want to trigger each time a checkbox is clicked. The triggered function clears all checkboxes and only checks the clicked one. The checkboxes should now behave like radio buttons.

Your controller might look like this:

```
app.controller("MyCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.devices = [{
        name: "LED",
        checked: false
    }, {
        name: "LED 2",
        checked: false
    }, {
        name: "LED 3",
        checked: false
    }];

    $scope.change = function(device) {
        angular.forEach($scope.devices, function(item) {
            item.checked = false;
        });
        device.checked = true;
    };
}]);
```

It is not necessary to create the `canBeChecked` property you mention.

Here's the full working example: http://jsfiddle.net/zxdr8/

Comment: Using `ng-change` is more semantically correct, though `ng-click` probably works in most modern browsers.

Comment: I know, and I agree. However, `ng-change` allows a checkbox to be unchecked too. If the OP wants a radio-like behaviour, it makes sense to disallow unchecking. This is why I used `ng-click` instead of `ng-change`.

Comment: I have to say, I'm liking this one more, purely because you can't un-check a `checkbox`!

Comment: Funnily enough, come to think of it, I did this in an earlier project, only difference is, I was using Knockout not Angular, nd I understand that better (maybe not for long though :) )

Comment: Can you up vote my question just so it is 0, thanks, no one said why they down voted it....

Answer (score 1):

If you must use checkboxes, here is how you would do it.

Markup:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="device in devices">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="device.checked" ng-change="checkDevice(device)"> {{ device.name }}
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.devices = [{
     name: "LED",
     checked: false,
     id: "98"
  },{
     name: "LED 2",
     checked: false,
     id: "8"
  },{
     name: "LED 3",
     checked: false,
     id: "78"
  }];

$scope.checkDevice = function (device) {
    for (var i = 0, len = $scope.devices.length; i < len; ++i) {
        if ($scope.devices[i] !== device)
             $scope.devices[i].checked = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `checked` and `canBeChecked` properties seems like merely an UI thing. In my opinion, you should not be creating a custom data models and duplicating unnecessary properties just to do that. Believe me, I did things like that too when started using Angular, but there are much better ways.

Consider storing selected data in other location (model, service, controller, whatever). And maybe if you can store just an ID (primitive property), you can do your "checkbox-radio-like-element" like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="device in devices">
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="{{device.id}}" ng-false-value="" ng-model="some.storage">
    {{device.name}}
  </label>
</div>
```

And thats all you need, no background code needed. When Angular team implements interpolation support for `ngTrueValue` and `ngFalseValue` directives, you will be able to store the whole objects and reset model to e.g. null.